# Input Box That Changes Page Title

Tags: javascript, html

I wish to make an input box in an iframe that changes the title of the page that the iframe is on. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <input type="text" name="name" id="title" value="start typeing" />

<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('title').onkeyup = myFun;
        function myFun() {
            window.parent.document.title = this.value;
        };
    </script>
```

This is working perfect on my end.
Place the input tag and script into your document of the iFrame.

Comment: k i am trying that but you must understand that i am completely illiterate in javascript. What must i change in the coding to get it to work for my webpage? My iframe's id is "left" and the page is at /research.html

Comment: Oh okay then thanks! I figured out what i was doing wrong. I knew i was bad at programming but now i realize i probably need to look up even the most basic of aspects! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use
`window.parent.document.title=$("#textboxId").val()`