# Javascript to change page title based on input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, page-title

Based on the similar question found at
[Input Box That Changes Page Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863994/input-box-that-changes-page-title):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Old title</title>
<body>

<h1 id="h1"></h1>

<input type="text" name="name" id="iText" value="start typeing" />


<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input id ="iText" type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
  document.getElementById('iText').onkeyup = myFunction;
  function myFunction() {
    window.parent.document.title = document.getElementById("iText").value;
    document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML = document.title;
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is working perfectly with the `onkeyup` event. However, I don't want the flicking but only change page title once when people click the `submit`. But my code is not working as expected.

Basically what i wanna do is when user writes something to input and submits it, the page title will be changed to the input.

Comment: Where's the code that you tried with the submit? Are you doing anything to stop the form from being submitted and reloading the page?

Comment: @j08691, I realized the very problem after I asked then took a deeper look. I'm not a frontend/JS developer, this is the best I can come up with -- how can I handle when the form is being submitted? I'd hope the JS can handle the `?param=xx` from the url as well as from the form input.